# Can't get dropdown to populate from MySQL database

Tags: php, select, drop-down-menu, mysqli

I would like to create a simple select drop down, to be populated by a table in my MYSQL database.
Here is my code:

```
$q = 'SELECT * FROM Shipmethods';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $q);

echo '<select name="shipmethod">';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)); 
{   
    echo '<option value="' . $row['shipmethodid'] . '">' . $row['shipmethoddesc'] . '</option>';
}

echo '</select>';

mysqli_free_result($result); // free up the results
```

}

There is no connection error, no typos in table name or column names.  The HTML output shows that a select option exists, but it is empty.  I would like to use mysqli for this.

There seem to be countless topics already on this subject, but as far as I can see, my code matches the correct answers of those already answered questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you check that the query returns anything? I would also suggest that you use prepared statements since you're using MySQLi already. But you should try your query in a console, or in PHPMyAdmin, or whatever you can. MySQL can fail spectacularly, but without built-in checks you'd never know it in the browser... just no results. Perhaps you can post the contents of $row with `print print_r($row, true);`.

Comment: add `print_r($row);` inside the while loop, see what that returns

Comment: Swapnesh nailed it.  However, your code also suffers from the "query and forget" weakness.  You query, store the result in $result, but you don't actually check $result.  You should have if ($result) {  // now try and fetch  } else { printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($connection)); }    Of course as Ian pointed out, the query could also return an empty result set.

Comment: @gview  just using my debugging knowledge, as at my start i made a lot..now helping others :)

Comment: The errant semicolon is not the problem. That would throw a Parse error. I'm sure, either the query is blowing up (mistyped column name, etc.) or not returning anything.

Comment: C'mon @Coleen, I wanna see an array already! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `;` from this line, rest code seems fine to me, let me know if it works or not --

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
```

To

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
```

Comment: This can't possibly be anything other than a transcription error. PHP would throw a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in blah.php on line x`.

Comment: @IanAtkin we can only provide a pointer towards the solution..as we are not head readers...what about if he suppress all types of warnings/notice etc..even then its not going to reflect any error :)

Comment: @IanAtkin its ok..I love to learn a lot with knowledge sharing, it may or actually possible you are quite better than what I am :)

Comment: No, not better. I've just had a lot of queries blow up with no obvious reason. That's why I advocate setting up logging properly. It can save days of time!

Comment: @Ian, Incorrect. It will not throw an error, because it is not a syntax error.

Comment: @IanAtkin i will do it on behalf of gview..check this http://codepad.org/3Hgs2qOf  :)

Comment: I just proved it... so do the right thing and reverse your downvote.

Comment: Yeah, it does timeout. But the OP's code blows up with the semicolon. Go figure.

Comment: Swapnesh - thank you, thank you, thank you!  You have no idea.  I tried the full code through a syntax checker, and have error_reporting set to E_ALL - nothing came up regarding my ever-lovin' semi-colon.  When parsed through my localhost, I would see my page, formatted and everything, with an empty select dropdown.  But now, finally.... success.  Cheers!

Comment: @Coleen sounds good... ur now in a comfort zone :) have a good Xmas time :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, based on the evidence we have, the most likely issue, other than an empty result set, is the issue that swapnesh identified, which is clearly a logic error.  I'm providing this illustration, which simulates the problem to make it clear that it is NOT a syntax error to do what was accidently done here.  The misplaced semicolon in essence causes the following block to be entered only after the while loop has been exhausted.

Consider this example:

```
<?php

$r = array(1,2,3,4);

function fetchit(&$r) {
    return array_pop($r);
}


while ($val = fetchit($r))
{
    echo $val;
}
```

This would be the intended use.  Now what happens if the script has this code instead?

```
<?php

$r = array(1,2,3,4);

function fetchit(&$r) {
    return array_pop($r);
}


while ($val = fetchit($r));
{
    echo $val;
}
```

Trying these you will see that both scripts run without error.  Although unnecessary, php does not care if you randomly include an uneeded block somewhere in your script { }, and it also does not care if an if, while, for etc, is followed by a block. It's in fact common practice for people to shorten up code with:

```
if (//somecondition)
    statement;
```

Many people frown on that practice but it's legal and programmers use it all the time.

Comment: You're right - they run without error and pass syntax checkers, but it sure did mess up my morning :)  Thanks for the further explanation!  And actually, in the code I posted here, I omitted my database connection information and error checking in an attempt to be more concise - I'll make sure to add it all next time.